# What protocols are used to create a chat application for iOS, Android and Microsoft?

Tags: android, ios, chat, windows-mobile, protocols

I have an asp.net application talking to a SQL DB with iOS, Android and Microsoft mobile applications all talking to one DB. 
Individuals and chat on any platform and receive the message on a one-to-one or one-to-group. Currently im doing a 2sec refresh. 
What technology or best practice is used for an chatting application ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use WebSockets or can use long polling or COMET: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: Which is the best practice proven solutions from them all ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSockets or can use long polling or COMET. All of them are well proven and the latest one that is getting wide acceptance is WebSockets with Javascript.